# presentModalViewController breaks UITextView layout when dismissed

Tags: ios, layout, uitextview, offset, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've a very strange problem when using presentModalViewController.
I've an app with many UIViewController that display UIButton and UITextViews. I manually offset the text in UITextViews to align them top or bottom depending of some criterias.

Everything works perfectly except when I use presentModalViewController to display an MFMessageComposeViewController. When I dismiss the MFMessageComposeViewController the UITextViews which are behind have lost their offset and the text align at the bottom is now at the top of the UITextView ...

If I keep 99% of the code and just don't call presentModalViewController everything works.
I've looked in viewWillAppear, layoutSubviews, etc to try to find where my offset is reseted but I'm stuck.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to know if you have found a solution to this issue. I am also facing the same problem. :(